# Product of three binomials

Tags: calculus

Suppose you have a product of three binomials each of which can be represented as binomial series:

$(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\times (1+4x)^{\frac{1}{2}}\times (1-2x)^{-2}$

How do you find the center and radius of convergence of this product.

I am trying to refresh my understanding of power series... I am stuck on this and would be very happy if someone could help me how to move on with it...

So far I know that the Taylor series expansions for these binomials are:

$
(1-x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1-\frac{x}{2}-\frac{x^{2}}{8}-\frac{x^{3}}{16}-\ldots 
(\text{about }x=0)$

$(1+4x)^{\frac{1}{2}}=1+2x-2x^{2}+4x^{3}-\ldots (\text{about } x=0)$

$(1-2x)^{-2}=1+4x+12x^{2}+32x^{3}+\ldots (\text{about }x=0)$

Comment: don't use the Taylor expansion use the binomial expansion.Using the Taylor series is too much work.

Comment: Where does each of those series converge? So where do they *all* converge?

Answer (score 1):

You need all three to converge.  You have singularities at $1, -\frac 14, \frac 12$  You can expand around any point in the complex plane, then the radius of convergence will be the distance to the closest one.  If you expand around $0$, the closest one is at $-\frac 14$ so the radius of convergence will be $\frac 14$.  If you expand around $11$ the closest one is $1$ so the radius of convergence will be $10$.